# Why do I get "Failed to start kernel" message when creating a new file with Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I hope this will prove to be a silly user error by someone new to Jupyter - thanks in advance for your forbearance! I have installed Ananconda (Navigator version 1.9.2), created an environment, and activated it. I invoked Jupyter with "jupyter notebook" from the command line after "cd-ing" into the directory where I intend to work. This brings up Jupyter in a new browser tab as expected, but when I try to create a new file, I get the following (Windows 10 machine, Python version 3.6.6, simplejson was installed in this environment with "pip install simplejson", Jupyter Notebook version 5.7.0). In spite of the error, a new file called Untitled.ipynb did get created:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1592, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 73, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 160, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 259, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 204, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 128, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: "jupyter kernelspec list" does show that I have a python3 kernel:

Available kernels:
  python3    C:\Users\Ajit\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\phd\share\jupyter\kernels\python3

Comment: I have ipykernel version 5.1.0

Comment: py4j IS installed.